# How do I merge 2 audio files into a 2.1 audio file via FFmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have 2 audio files, "LowPassedAudio.wav" and "HighPassedAudio.wav" generated by FFmpeg.

I need to merge them into one 2.1 audio stream where HighPassedAudio is the L and R channels, and LowPassedAudio is the LFE channel, how can I do this?

I'm not very knowledgable when it comes to FFmpeg, and its filter system just yet, so I haven't known what to try, so any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you mean the FL and FR channels?

Comment: I did, my apologies! I'm not too knowledgable on what means what

Comment: Fixing my answer

Answer (score 1):

The [join filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#join) can do the trick:

```
ffmpeg -i LowPassedAudio.wav -i HighPassedAudio.wav -filter_complex "join=inputs=2:channel_layout=2.1:map=0.0-LFE|1.0-FL|1.0-FR"
```